# Load a Module on demand from multiple points

Tags: c#, module, prism

I'm implementing a Unity PRISM module on demand using IModuleManager. Suppose there are multiple points where functionality from the module is required. Am I right to call `moduleManager.LoadModule("MyModule")` at each of these points even if the module might have already loaded previously? It's not going to reload is it?

And is this best practice?

Thanks

Comment: Why was this question marked down?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Agreeing with Viktor, the response in [this thread](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/429481) suggests not to call LoadModule but to check the ModuleState using IModuleCatalog and IModuleManager.

Here is the code snippet from that post:

```
(...)

 var module = this.moduleCatalog.Modules.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ModuleName == "MyModule");
            if (module != null)
            {
                if (module.State != ModuleState.Initialized)
                {
                    moduleManager.LoadModuleCompleted += moduleManager_LoadModuleCompleted;
                    moduleManager.LoadModule("MyModule");
                }
                else
                {

                    //Initialization logic

                }
            }
        }

        void moduleManager_LoadModuleCompleted(object sender, LoadModuleCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            moduleManager.LoadModuleCompleted -= moduleManager_LoadModuleCompleted;

            if (e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == "MyModule")
            {
                //Initialization logic
            }
        }

(...)
```

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to summarize the linked material here. Otherwise, the answer is at risk of losing its usefulness due to link rot.

Comment: -1: Links are not answers. And if you agree with Viktor, you should accept his answer, then write your happiness in a comment on that answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit While Victor's answer is beneficial and I'm glad he wrote it, I used the answer from the link hence why I've added it here.

Answer (score 1):

When You look at [Prism Modularity Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921068%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

You will find this method which is responsible for loading Module

```
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);

        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            if ((this.moduleTrackingState != null) && (this.moduleTrackingState.ExpectedInitializationMode == InitializationMode.OnDemand) && (this.moduleTrackingState.ModuleInitializationStatus == ModuleInitializationStatus.NotStarted))
            {
                this.RaiseRequestModuleLoad();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note that there is a condition preventing call to `this.RaiseRequestModuleLoad();`  when `ModuleInitializationStatus` is not `ModuleInitializationStatus.NotStarted`.

I tried to get rid of that and discovered following:

1. There is no exception thrown when you call `moduleManager.LoadModule("YourModule");` multiple times.
2. Module's `Initialize` method is called only the first time you load the module.

Module loading means that the module assembly is transferred from disk into memory. So... If it is reloaded every time You really shouldn't do that. Just to answer your question "Is this best practice?" I have to say... It's most certainly NOT. I am not able to tell you whether it's reloaded each time you call `moduleManager.LoadModule("YourModule");` but IMHO You should load module only once simply because they do it once as well.